# Why the React cllient Axios send HTTP with an extended local URL

Tags: node.js, typescript, http

When I using React send an HTTP request, I found the client send an extended http request with the local URL route. In the URL `https://tex.example.top/userpage/pwd/retrieve`, do a http request using Axios like this:

```
export function verifySmsCode(doc: VerifyReq) {
  const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'put',
    url: '/texpub/user/verify',
    data: JSON.stringify(doc)
  };
  const actionTypeString: string = PwdActionType[PwdActionType.VERIFY];
  return XHRClient.requestWithActionType(config, actionTypeString, store);
}
```

But the client send 2 request, one is `/texpub/user/verify`, the other one is `/userpage/pwd/retrieve`. And the second request shows error `405 Method Not Allowed`, the request type is document, shows error `net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`.

[image]

Am I missing something? why the client send a http request with local web URL? This is the web turned to:

```
This dev-tex.example.top page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://dev-tex.example.top/userpage/pwd/retrieve
HTTP ERROR 404
```

When I refresh the page, the UI will shows out.